# Applicative instance trying to use monoidal functors

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids

I'm learning Haskell and trying to do exercises from book Haskell Programming from first principles and I'm stack trying to write applicative for Pair type

```
 data Pair a = Pair a a deriving Show
```

I have seen some other examples on web but I'm trying somewhat different applicative functor, I'm trying to utilize monoidal structure of this type. Here is what I have

```
data Pair a = Pair a a deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor Pair where
     fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (f x) (f y)

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Pair a) where
    (Pair x y) <> (Pair x' y') = Pair (x <> x') (y <> y')

instance Applicative Pair where
    pure x = Pair x x 
    (Pair f g) <*> p = fmap f p <> fmap g p
```

Unfortunately this will not compile:

```
* No instance for (Semigroup b) arising from a use of `<>'
  Possible fix:
    add (Semigroup b) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        (<*>) :: forall a b. Pair (a -> b) -> Pair a -> Pair b
* In the expression: fmap f p <> fmap g p
  In an equation for `<*>': (Pair f g) <*> p = fmap f p <> fmap g p
  In the instance declaration for `Applicative Pair'
```

And this is where I'm stack; I don't see how can I add typeclass constraint to Applicative definition and I thought that making type Pair instance of Semigroup is enough.

Other solutions that I have seen are like

```
Pair (f g) <*> Pair x y = Pair (f x) (g y)
```

but these solutions don't utilize monoidal part of Pair type

Is it even possible to make this applicative the way I't trying?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you are using the term "monoidal functor" to mean something other than its [actual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor).

Comment: You're running into the same problem that means `Set` can't be a `Monad` (or `Applicative`), so the many discussions around that problem floating around the web should also be interesting to you. Consider googling "constrained monad" for many, many starting points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's true that `Applicative` is the class representing monoidal functors (specifically, **Hask** endofunctors which are monoidal), Allen&Moronuki present this unfortunately in a way that seems to suggest a direct relation between the `Monoid` and `Applicative` classes. *There is, in general, no such relation*! (The `Writer` type  does define one particular `Applicative` instance based on the `Monoid` class, but that's an extremely special case.)
This spawned [a rather extended discussion at another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50703828/745903).

What the “monoidal” in “monoidal functor” refers to is a monoidal structure on *the category's objects*, i.e. on Haskell types. Namely, you can combine any two types to a tuple-type. This has per se nothing whatsoever to do with the `Monoid` class, which is about combining two *values* of a single type to a value of the same type.

`Pair` does allow an `Applicative` instance, but you can't base it on the `Semigroup` instance, although the definition actually looks quite similar:

```
instance Applicative Pair where
  pure x = Pair x x
  Pair f g <*> Pair p q = Pair (f p) (g q)
```

However, you can now define the `Semigroup` instance *in terms of this*:

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Pair a) where
  (<>) = liftA2 (<>)
```

That, indeed, is a valid `Semigroup` instance for *any* applicative, but it's usually not the definition you want (often, containers have a natural combination operation that never touches the contained elements, e.g. list concatenation).

Comment: Thanks! Being beginner it is somewhat hard to follow discussions but I think I understood part of it: applicative instance should work for all types that implement it while my implementation depended on fact  that type should implement instance of Semigroup (all the types regardless how deep they are in structure) and second the "monoidal" part should be about structure (in my case it is Pair constructor) not the values which I was trying to combine (this is what Monoid is doing)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `Pair` is an `Applicative` the way you want it to be, `Applicative` states that

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

should work for all functions in first position whereas you want

```
(<*>) :: Semigroup b => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b.
```

If Pair was always a `Semigroup` (like `Maybe` or `List` for example) your reasoning would be sound, but you need the pre-requisite of the `Pair`-containee to be `Semigroup`.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: `Pair` can't be made an `Applicative` in the way you want, because `Applicative f` demands that `f a` "feel applicative-y" for *any* `a`, even non-`Semigroup` `a`s. Consider writing an alternative class and implementing it:

```
class CApplicative f where
    type C f
    pure :: C f a => a -> f a
    app  :: C f b => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance CApplicative Pair where
    type C Pair = Semigroup
    pure x = Pair x x
    app (Pure f g) p = fmap f p <> fmap g p
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be derive since base 4.17.0.0, which includes the via types `Generically` and `Generically1`. This will derive the same instances as leftaroundabout writes:

```hs
{-# Language DeriveGeneric      #-}
{-# Language DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# Language DerivingVia        #-}

import Data.Monoid
import GHC.Generics

data Pair a = Pair a a
  deriving
  stock (Generic, Generic1)

  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via Generically (Pair a)

  deriving (Functor, Applicative)
  via Generically1 Pair
```

Alternatively you can lift `Semigroup` and `Monoid` through the `Applicative`

```
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid, Num)
  via Ap Pair a
```