# A categorical view on applicative containers

Tags: haskell, functor, dependent-type, applicative, category-theory

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50717675/474311) from Conor McBride (pigworker) discusses `Applicative` functors that are also [*containers*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397505003373?via%3Dihub) (data types given by a set of shapes and a family of positions).
Among other things, he mentions that:

- A polymorphic function between two containers has two components: one acting on shapes and one on positions.
- The shape of applicative containers form a monoid under an operation related to the application operation, `<*>`.

I was wondering if a similar analysis can be carried in a categorical setting and if I could reach the same conclusions using category theory (mainly because I feel more at ease with category theory than with dependent type theory).

I know that `Applicative` functors are [monoidal functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor) (from `(Set, ×, 1)` to `(Set, ×, 1)`) and I believe that containers can be regarded as [functors shapely over lists](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.2179&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (as suggested [here](https://www.fceia.unr.edu.ar/~mauro/pubs/TraverseLaws.pdf) or [here](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/uitbaf.pdf)) – but I'm not very comfortable with this concept or this assertion.
Is this the right way of thinking about applicative containers, as monoidal functors that are shapely over lists?

P.S.: Let me know if you feel that stackoverflow is not the appropriate place to ask this sort of question.